# How to simulate "press and hold"(long press) key action in casperjs/phantomjs?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, keydown, keyup

I'm using casperjs to test a grid-like widget. The grid contains large number of rows. The rows can multiple-selected by press and hold Shift key, then click two dirrent rows, then the rows among twice click will get selected. Here is my code segment to test this functionality:

```
casper.start(mytesturl);

this.then(function sendKeydown(){
    //send Shift keydown event
    this.page.sendEvent('keydown', '', null, null, 0x02000000);
});
this.then(function startClick(){
    //click row 0
    this.click('#row0', '50%', '50%');
});



this.then(function secondClick(){
    //click row 3
    this.click('#row3', '50%', '50%');

});

this.then(function sendKeyup(){
    //send Shift keyup event
    this.page.sendEvent('keyup', '', null, null, 0x02000000);
    this.capture('afterKeyup.png');

});
```

I also tried "this.page.sendEvent('keyup', this.page.event.key.Shift);", but both failed, the afterKeyup.png alway shows only the row3 is selected, instead of rows 0 to 3 selected.

I guess the problem is that, the Casperjs or Phantomjs don't retain the keydown status when run into other steps, so each time I send keyup event, it acts as the Shift key is firstly pressed, test suite don't think the Shift key is now hold ("keydown").

So I want to know how should I do to achieve pressing and holding Shift key along with click event?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering an event on the page, find which node is listening (Ex. with chrome dev tools) for the required events, then :

```
// node where event listeners are listening
var element = document.querySelector('foo#bar');

var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
evt.initEvent('keydown', false, true);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```